# Remove prefix from a LIST of files in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of files with a common name pattern, all with the same structure (prefix `ave.`):

```
ave.20050716-12:00:00.stat_profiles.nc 
ave.20050816-12:00:00.stat_profiles.nc  
ave.20081116-00:00:00.stat_profiles.nc  
ave.20120215-12:00:00.stat_profiles.nc
ave.19990316-12:00:00.stat_profiles.nc  
ave.20020616-00:00:00.stat_profiles.nc
```

My question is: How do I remove `ave.` from **all** the files in a file list / folder?

Comment: @Corion, I'm sorry, I really don't know how to apply it to my concrete solution. I'm completely new at this!

Comment: Then work through the parts of the answer I linked, try them, and maybe ask us with a concrete failing example where it fails to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `rename` utility from the `util-linux` package available, it makes this kind of task very easy.

From its `man` :

> ```
>   rename [options] expression replacement file...
> ```
>
> `rename` will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of *expression* in their name by *replacement*.

So in your case :

```
rename ave. '' ave.*
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop and [string substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

```
for file in ave.*
do 
    mv "$file" "${file#ave.}"
done
```

This is just an example to get you started and you should check for things such as already existing files with the name without "ave.".